# Windows Phone 7 dev: How to autoscroll textblock's text Horizontally

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have this textblock `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-3,12,0" FontSize="27"/>` , and I want to tell me a way in order to text, scrolled automatically when it is longer than screen.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a [`ScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,-3,12,0" FontSize="27"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: it not helps me out, i want the text scrolls horizonally automatically without interaction from user...

Comment: Auto-scrolling (marquees) text don't belong in a mobile app. While you can probably conjure up some weird animation, I would **strongly** advice against it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it isn't a good practice, but look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15065921/840627) if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still interest and wants to do one for yourself, please take a look at my article on [How to create marquee TextBlock on Windows Phone](http://www.fantageek.com/66/wp7-how-to-create-marquee-textblock/)

It uses Storyboard to perform animation so that all are handled by GPU