# Windows Phone - Marquee With Template

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

In windows phone i could easily marquee a textblock. But is there any solution to marquee list of items for which i can define template and bind it to a list of items.

Thanks
Gokoulane Ravi

Comment: In windows phone i could easily marquee a textblock.

Comment: could you tell me how to implement this

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a WP style...

1. Add storyboard to page resources:

   ```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>  
       <Storyboard x:Name="Scroll" RepeatBehavior="Forever">  
          <DoubleAnimation From="480" To="-480" Storyboard.TargetName="translate" Storyboard.TargetProperty="X" Duration="0:0:5" />  
       </Storyboard>  
   </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
   ```
2. Add ScrollViewer, add StackPanel inside and TextBlock inside:

   ```
          <ScrollViewer x:Name="LongScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="0,212,0,339" IsEnabled="False" >
               <StackPanel Margin="0" Height="58">
                   <TextBlock x:Name="LongTextBlock" Text="Very long, real long, it's a long text." Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming="None" TextWrapping="NoWrap">
                       <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                           <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
                       </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                   </TextBlock>
               </StackPanel>
           </ScrollViewer>
   ```
3. In page's Loaded method make sure TextBlock's text is long enough for scrolling:

   ```
       Size size = new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
       this.LongTextBlock.Measure(size);
       size = this.LongTextBlock.DesiredSize;

       if (size.Width > this.ActualWidth)
       {
           this.Scroll.Begin();
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. However you'll need to write custom XAML to achieve this functionality. Blend can help you over here to create that custom animation and run as marquee.